# Array changes when element retrieved

Tags: c++, gdb

Edit: Added constructors and add function

Consider the following three blocks:

```
//ONE
template<typename T>
class List1 {
private:
    uint32_t capacity;
    uint32_t used;
    T* data;
    void checkGrow() {
            if (used < capacity)
                    return;
            T* old = data;
            capacity*=2;
            data = (T*)new char[sizeof(T) * capacity];
            memcpy(data, old, sizeof(T)*used);
            delete (void*)old;
    }
public:
    List1() : capacity(1), used(0), data((T*)new char [sizeof(T)]) {}
    List1(uint32_t initialSize) :
            capacity(initialSize), used(0), data((T*)new char[sizeof(T)]) {}

    List1(const List1& orig) :
            capacity(orig.capacity), used(orig.used), data((T*)new char[used * sizeof(T)]) {
            memcpy(data, orig.data, used * sizeof(T));
    }
    uint32_t serializeSize() const { return sizeof(used) + used*sizeof(T); }
    char* read(char* p) {
            used = *(uint32_t*)p;
            p += sizeof(uint32_t);
            data = (T*)new char[used*sizeof(T)];
            memcpy(p, data, used * sizeof(T));
            return p + used*sizeof(T);
    }
    char* write(char* p) {
            *(uint32_t*)p = used;
            p += sizeof(uint32_t);
            memcpy(p, data, used * sizeof(T));
            return p + used * sizeof(T);
    }

    ~List1() { delete [] data; }

    void add(const T& v) {
            checkGrow();
      data[used++] = v;        
    }
    uint32_t getUsed() const{
            return used;
    }
    uint32_t getCapacity() const{
            return capacity;
    }

    //const T& operator [](int i) const { return data[i]; }
    //T& operator [](int i) { return data[i]; }
    T getData (int i) const{
            return data[i];
    }
    uint32_t size() const { return used * sizeof(T); }
};

//TWO
List1<uint32_t> temp=in.readList<uint32_t>(); // <List1<uint32_t>>();
//BREAKPOINT HERE
for(uint i=0;i<15;i++){
    //cout<<temp[i]<<endl;
    cout<<temp.getData(i)<<endl;
}

//THREE
template<typename T>
T _read() {
    T temp = *(T*)p;
    p += sizeof(T);
    availRead -= sizeof(T);
    return temp;
}

template<typename T>
T read(){
    //cout << (uint64_t)p << endl;
    checkAvailableRead(sizeof(T));
    return _read<T>();
}
template<typename T>

List1<T> readList(){
    uint32_t len = read<uint32_t>();
    List1<T> temp(len);
    for (uint i = 0 ; i < len; i++){
        T val =read<T>();
        temp.add(val);
        //HERE: For some reason code does not work without this print statement
        //cout<<temp.getData(i)<<endl;
        }
    return temp;
}
```

Basically the issue is that the value of data changes from after returning from getData as shown below.

```
gdb) p/u *temp.data@15  
$1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
(gdb) p/u *temp.data@15  
$2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
(gdb) p/u *data@15  
$3 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
[New Thread 8444.0xad8]
(gdb) p/u *data@15  
$4 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
[New Thread 8444.0x214c]
(gdb) p/u *temp.data@15  
$5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 83, 0, 2150008464, 1, 3742232646, 0, 168272, 6, 0}
```

For some reason adding a print statement to readList fixes the issue, but that isn't a reasonable solution. I've tried a few different variations on the code but none of them worked.

I'm not sure what the issue is or how to even begin debugging as the problem occurs between the return statement and the next iteration of the loop (there's nothing to step into there).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably rule of 3 violation. Need to see your constructors (& destructor).

Comment: A read access like in `return data[i];` with `T` as return (a value) shouldn't change any contents of anything else except there is undefined behavior. This could be a sign that your list storage and the return value share storage. That must not be - it's a bug. I would check for proper allocation... (Yeah, or something else wrong like mentioned by @Mat.)

Comment: _For some reason adding a print statement to readList fixes the issue_ another thing how [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) may expose...

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: How _add()_ is implemented ? if _data_ point to a too small vector or a wrong address _getData()_ can read memory (including stack) modified elsewhere and may be through your printing. I remark that the values into the vector are equals to their indexes which is also the parameter of _getData()_ called by the printing. So as it was already said give us the definition of your constructor(s) and _add()_

Comment: Added constructor/destructor and add function.

Comment: One of your three constructors allocates enough space to hold the indicated capacity. Another allocates enough space to hold the amount used. The third allocates space that matches neither the amount used nor the capacity. You should probably pick one uniform way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

```
List1(const List1& orig) :
        capacity(orig.capacity), used(orig.used), data((T*)new char[used * sizeof(T)]) {
        memcpy(data, orig.data, used * sizeof(T));
}
```

For `List1` to work correctly, there must never be a `List1` whose `capacity` is greater than the actual allocated size. However, this creates a new `List1` that violates this invariant if `orig` has a `capacity` greater than its `used`.

You probably meant `capacity(orig.used)`.

Same issue here:

```
List1(uint32_t initialSize) :
        capacity(initialSize), used(0), data((T*)new char[sizeof(T)]) {}
```

If you set `capacity` to `initialSize`, you can't allocate space for just 1 `T`.

This is also broken `delete (void*)old;`. What you allocate with `new[]`, you must free with `delete[]`.

Note that `List1` can only be used to hold POD types (plain old data) that don't have constructors or destructors. If you're trying to use `List1` to hold anything more complex, you're way off base with your design.

Comment: I'll give that a try, but for the context that constructor is used in it shouldn't matter. Will post afterwards.

Comment: @tpnam You didn't give us the code to reproduce the error.

Comment: Above didn't work. I'll see if I can put together a working example within a single file as the various components above are all separate.

Comment: This is also broken `delete (void*)old;`. What you allocate with `new[]`, you must free with `delete[]`.